# Rule cannot get activated after certen number of hit

Tags: drools

I use org.drools.runtime.rule.StatelessRuleSession.execute(Object object) method to match on my CollectorPluginData object. it has type and some other properties in a map collection. I keep a KnowledgeAgent as spring bean, every time i will create a StatelessKnowledgeSession from this agent.
It just working fine for if I feed the session with my disk data. What i find is, if I feed the same data for more than 20 times in a loop, the firest 20 could successfuly get hit, but after that, if i keep feed the seesion with same disk data, the rule with not get activated. It seems i get some limitation in the rules engine.

a sample data is here:

```
{
  "hostName": "host291",
  "timeStamp": "2014-12-30T22:59:55",
  "pluginName": "DiskCollectorPlugin",
  "jsonType": "Monitor",
  "componentList":
  [
    {
      "type":"Disk",
      "id":"252_1",
      "name":"Enclosure 252 Disk 1",
      "properties":
      {
        "isGlobalHotSpare":0,
        "isSupported":1,
        "pdDeviceType":"SAS",
        "scsiDeviceType":"Disk",
        "mediaErrorCount":0,
        "linkSpeed":3,
        "maxSupportedSpeed":"6G",
        "otherErrorCount":0,
        "predFailCount":0,
        "isForcedPdGuid":0,
        "coercedSize":1951170560,
        "lastFailedPredEventSeqNum":0,
        "shieldCounter":0,
        "isForeign":0,
        "currentComponentState":"Unconfigured Good",
        "isPdInVd":0,
        "driveReadyForRemoval":0,
        "isDedicatedHotSpare":0,
        "rawSize":1953525168,
        "slotNumber":1,
        "nonCoercedSize":1952476592,
        "enclosureId":252,
        "pdMediaType":"Rotating Media, HDD",
        "pdPowerState":"Spun Down",
        "temperatureInCelsius":255,
        "shieldDiagCompletionTime":"0000-00-00T00:00:00"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

My rule to math this data is:

```
rule "Disk Rule"
when
    $diskData : CollectorPluginData(pluginName == "DiskCollectorPlugin", 
                                    $componentList : componentList)
    $component: Component(type == "Disk",
                          properties["scsiDeviceType"] == "Disk")
                from $componentList  
then
    System.out.println("Rule get activated.");
end
```

I also try to remove the second condition on Component "properties["scsiDeviceType"] == "Disk"", and the limitation gone. The rule can always get activated no matter how many time I feed the same data to the session.

The method I used to run this rule:

```
public void processCollectorPluginData(CollectorPluginData cpd)
{
    analysisReport = new AnalysisReport();
    collectorPluginData = cpd;
    analyzerPluginData = null;
    logCollectorFiles = Collections.<String> emptyList();
    logCollectorCommands = Collections.<String> emptyList();
    StatelessKnowledgeSession ksession =    knowledgeAgent.getKnowledgeBase().newStatelessKnowledgeSession();
    KnowledgeBase knowledgeBase = knowledgeAgent.getKnowledgeBase();
    int retryCount = 0;
    while (knowledgeBase.getKnowledgePackages().size() == 0 && retryCount < 10)
    {
      System.out.println("ERROR: Issue with rules policy update, move back to previos poilcies");
      ksession = knowledgeAgent.getKnowledgeBase().newStatelessKnowledgeSession();
      knowledgeBase = knowledgeAgent.getKnowledgeBase();
      retryCount++;
    }
    if (knowledgeBase.getKnowledgePackages().size() == 0 && retryCount == 10)
    {
      throw new RuntimeException("ERROR: Rule knowledge base is null, drl files compilation issue");
    }
    ksession.addEventListener(new DroolsEventListener());
    ksession.setGlobal("ruleEngineService", this);
    ksession.execute(cpd);
    analysisReport.setAnalyzerPluginData(analyzerPluginData);
    analysisReport.setCollectorPluginData(collectorPluginData);
    try
    {
      postAnalysisReport();
      postCollectLogJob(analysisReport, logCollectorFiles, logCollectorCommands);
      LOGGER.info("Analysis Report: " + mapper.writeValueAsString(analysisReport));
    }
    catch (JsonProcessingException | RestClientException e)
    {
      LOGGER.error("Received exception:", e);
    }
    return;
}
```

Where is problem? in my rule? Is there any limitation in Rule Engine?

Comment: The data sample contains a lot of irrelevant fields and properties, but `"scsiDeviceType":"Disk"` is missing, and so the rule shouldn't fire at all. - I can guess the Java types of Component and CollectorPluginData but I cannot guess the code with which you activate your session and how you feed your data, and whether there's other data that might match etc. etc.

Comment: It looks like a constraint jitting problem.. I agree with laune, does the rule ever fire at all with your sample data? 
Regardless, which version are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I attached a incorrect data. Have update the sample data. I use 5.6.0.Final.

Comment: @DavideSottara Another MVEL vs JITting smell? Although this is a direct access: properties["scsiDeviceType"] - no contains.

Comment: Whenever rules "stop firing" after a certain number of runs, jitting is always the first suspect :), especially when older versions like 5.5/5.6 are involved. 
I am travelling, so I won't be able to test the updated reproducer until next week

Comment: The same question was resolved in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27852305/drools-rules-is-not-being-fired-after-3-times

Answer (score 0):

I too facing the same issue rules are getting skipped after certain number of runs if i create the Stateless KnowledgeSession from the same knowledge base.

Comment: please describe which version you are using and provide a reproducer. It is almost impossible to help otherwise.